# Using Selenium with Phantomjs in node not returning results

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I have the following node route using selenium and chrome driver which is working correctly and returning expected html in the console:

```
    app.get('/google', function (req, res) {
      var driver = new webdriver
        .Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();

      driver.get('https://www.google.com')
      driver
        .manage()
        .window()
        .setSize(1200, 1024);
      driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated({xpath: '//*[@id="lst-ib"]'}));
      return driver
        .findElement({xpath: '//*[@id="lst-ib"]'})
        .sendKeys('stackoverflow' + webdriver.Key.RETURN)
        .then((html) => {
          return driver
            .findElement({xpath: '//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div'})
            .getAttribute("innerHTML")
        })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
        })
.then(() => {
      res
        .status(200)
        .send('ok')
    });
```

I have also installed the phantom js driver and tested that its working by returning the URL title - it works. When I use the above exact route and replace the chrome with phantomjs I get no results returned. There are no errors - just no print out in my console. The status and result are never sent to the browser so it doesn't appear to be stepping through promise chain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that there was different html being rendered depending on the user agent. By forcing a user agent I was able to retrieve the results i needed.
Here is the code snippet  replaced above to get this working.

```
.Builder()
// .forBrowser('phantomjs')
.withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()
.set("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"))
.build();
```